# Open up SharePoint application using SSO from custom web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, sharepoint-online

I have an external MVC application where I want to add the link which will automatically log in and open the SharePoint online portal in a separate tab(I will have the Sharepoint site URL username and password in encrypted form in the database).

New to SharePoint so will appreciate if someone can show me the right path.

Thanks in advance.